# What does this modality mean?

Tags: modal-verbs

> The storm raged more and more ferociously as the night
>   went on. Harry couldn't sleep. He shivered and turned over, trying to
>   get comfortable, his stomach rumbling with hunger. Dudley's snores
>   were drowned by the low rolls of thunder that started near midnight.
>   The lighted dial of Dudley's watch, which was dangling over the edge
>   of the sofa on his fat wrist, told Harry he'd be eleven in ten
>   minutes' time. He lay and watched his birthday tick nearer, wondering
>   if the Dursleys would remember at all, wondering where the letter
>   writer was now. 
>        Five minutes to go. Harry heard
>   something creak outside. He hoped the roof wasn't going to fall in,
>   although he might be warmer if it did. Four minutes to go. Maybe the
>   house in Privet Drive would be so full of letters when they got back
>   that he'd be able to steal one somehow. 
>        Three
>   minutes to go. Was that the sea, slapping hard on the rock like that?
>   And (two minutes to go) what was that funny crunching noise? Was the
>   rock crumbling into the sea?        One minute to go and
>   he'd be eleven. Thirty seconds. . . twenty. . . ten. . . nine ––
>   **maybe he'd wake Dudley up**, just to annoy him –– three. . . two. . . one. . . 
>        BOOM. 
>  (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

The modality would is very hard to guess what it means. Would you pick the right meaning in [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/would)?

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be willing to undelete [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10675/meaning-of-stacked-prepositions), would you?  I wrote up an answer and came back to find that the question was gone :-(

Comment: @snailboat, I'm regret you've made up an answer for it and found no place for it. It made some dispute over the rightness, so I deleted it. I'm undeleting it for your exquisite answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's number 1.

> **1** used as the past form of will when reporting what somebody has said or thought
>   *He said he would be here at eight o'clock (= His words were: ‘I will be there at eight o'clock.’).
>
>   She asked if I would help.
>
>   They told me that they probably wouldn't come.*

In this case, Harry actually thought "Maybe I will wake Dudley up, just to annoy him," while considering whether that would be a good course of action.

In narrating what happened, *will* becomes *would*, just as the first example in OALD.