# What do the stacked prepositions "away at" mean in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> My greatest privilege thrives in work that allows me to **carve away
> at words**, changing and reshaping them until they ring true.
>
> -- *[Benita Porter, The Power of Words](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/4210/)*

Does the phrase mean ‘carve away words at words’: make a good shape of words with words? Or what does it mean?

Comment: @snailboat, I added some words after colon.

Comment: It's ridiculously overblown pseudo-impressive flowery language. I don't think it makes a lot of sense to speak of "privileges thriving" in the first place, but I'd guess all Porter means is she enjoys getting paid to write. Which she thinks of as an artistic process involving *carving/sculpting* words into great prose - but in her case I would say it's just mangling/strangling language. The question itself is Lit Crit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Lit Crit

Comment: I have to go scrub my brain down after reading this sentence; but *away* may be understood as #4 [here](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/away+), and *at* points to the object upon which Ms. Porter exerts her efforts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd join you in that vote, but it would imply the presence here of Lit.

Comment: @StoneyB: Does the skilled mechanic not need some familiarity with clapped-out old bangers as well as finely-tuned Ferraris? (If only so he doesn't confuse the two! :) Anyway, moving beyond the *literary* (or *not-so-literary*) aspects, you'll doubtless know that the skilled sculptor *"chips/chisels/carves **away**"* at his block of stone/wood, to "reveal" the figure hidden within. It looks to me as if Porter has clumsily conflated two different and not-really-compatible elements in her "scribbling away".

Comment: ...and God knows why after carving these words she continues with a "sound as a bell" metaphor. Truly hopeless!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Quite so: three incompatible metaphors, evincing a fundamental confusion of formal, material and final cause ... I don't mind rebuilding honest junkers, but this lady's blown out her engine and seized up her transmission because she put her money into detailing and hard waxing instead of changing the oil.

Comment: I took the opportunity to write an answer focusing on the semantics of **away at** rather than this particular quote, but I did apply it to the quote at the end :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, If the question is about _Lit Crit_ (I did not really even try to **understand** the question), I think the problem this particular user is facing that (_if at all she is a learner_), she does not know whether it's a lit crit or not. If she posts in ELU and the question is rather simple, it gets closed there and if it's a lit crit and she is unable to understand that and posts here, the question gets closed. I think we need to think about this problem.

Comment: @Mistu4u: The link in StoneyB's first comment covers the general case for *[verb] **away** [at something]*. And it's easy to establish that [***carve** away at **words***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22carve+away+at+words%22&oq=%22carve+away+at+words%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6628j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) isn't a "set phrase" (all 7 instances found by Google there are for Porter's own usage). I don't see any reason why learners (as opposed to native speakers) should face any special difficulty in recognising this as an unusual/inept/figurative/"literary" usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked through COCA for collocates immediately preceding `away at`, writing down any phrases which I felt used **away at** in the same way as your quote.  (This was based on my personal judgment, and another person doing the same thing might have drawn the lines elsewhere.)  Since **away at** can be used in other ways, I checked the actual quotes for each to make sure they fit the usage I had in mind.  Here's what I found:

> blast away at
>   chew away at
>   chip away at
>   chisel away at
>   chomp away at
>   chop away at
>   clobber away at
>   cut away at
>   dig away at
>   drill away at
>   eat away at
>   gnaw away at
>   grind away at
>   hack away at
>   hammer away at
>   jackhammer away at
>   lick away at
>   melt away at
>   munch away at
>   nibble away at
>   peck away at
>   peel away at
>   pick away at
>   pound away at
>   rip away at
>   rub away at
>   saw away at
>   scrape away at
>   scratch away at
>   scrub away at
>   slash away at
>   slice away at
>   smash away at
>   snip away at
>   tear away at
>   wear away at
>   whack away at
>   wheedle away at
>   whittle away at

Some example sentences from COCA:

> 1. Romney's other rivals also worked to **chip away at his lead** as they fought through the Election Day media crush.
> 2. Instead, states kept **whittling away at the trust funds**, mostly by cutting unemployment insurance taxes at the behest of the business community.
> 3. Fear has been **eating away at the foundation of the economy** for a while, like the way termites eat away at the walls of a home, one bite at a time -- and then one bite and the whole wall comes down.
> 4. Then I notice that in the alley behind her car, a black rabbit is **nibbling away at my grandma's favorite corn** (that she planted herself).

In each of these sentences, we have a pattern that looks like this:

> *<verb>* ***away at*** *<noun phrase>*

The verb is an action by which the object represented by the noun phrase is gradually eroded, worn down, or reduced in some fashion.  To **chisel away at a block of stone** is to chisel repeatedly over time, perhaps until the block of stone is in the shape you want.  To **nibble away at food** is to nibble repeatedly over time, gradually reducing the food, perhaps until it is eaten entirely.  When **acid eats away at something**, it's being slowly eroded and worn away, perhaps until it's entirely gone.

It's a productive pattern, and you can put just about any verb with **away at** which fits these semantics.  Many such verbs fall into the category of eating (**chew, chomp, eat, gnaw, lick, munch, nibble, peck**), but more generally they fall into a category of acts which reduce a physical object in some fashion (**blast, chip, chisel, chop, clobber, cut, dig, drill, grind, hack, hammer, jackhammer, melt, peel, pick, pound, rip, rub, saw, scrape, scratch, scrub, slash, slice, smash, snip, tear, wear, whack, wheedle, whittle**).  Since it's productive, these lists are not complete, though any verbs I left out are probably quite infrequent.

Although these constructions literally express physical acts, they're often used metaphorically.  Of the four examples I gave above from COCA, examples 1-3 are all metaphorical.  Only example 4 is literal.

Now that we've got a good idea of how **away at** works, let's take a look at your example:

> My greatest privilege thrives in work that allows me to **carve away at words**, changing and reshaping them until they ring true.

Like **chisel away at** or **whittle away at**, the string **carve away at** literally expresses carving something gradually over time.  It makes the reader think of a sculptor, carefully carving a block of stone, gradually turning it into a work of art.  Of course, it's being used metaphorically here; there is no actual block of stone.  She's carving away at *words*, gradually shaping them into something else.  (Apparently, she's shaping them into a metaphorical bell.)

Comment: I am consumed with admiration at what a useful answer this is. Talk about making a silk purse from a sow's ear!