# Relationship between aspects and a particular usage of "away"

Tags: prepositions, aspect

The 6th entry for [**away**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/away) in MacMillan:

> [usually progressive] used for showing that someone does something
>   continuously or for a long time
>
> > Molly was at her desk **working away** as usual.
> >
> > The children were all **chattering away** happily.

I think this definition is a restricted usage of **away**, and it has to collocate with a dynamic verb.

However, not all dynamic verbs can work in this way:

> laugh away /
>   jump away
>   / 
>   hit away
>   /
>   dance away
>   / 
>   ponder away
>   /
>   wave away
>   /
>   make away
>   /
>   push away
>   /
>   submit away
>   /
>   integrate away
>   /
>   explain away / warn away / protect away / help away / shoot away

I think verbs with the atelic aspect can always work with this definition of **away**, is it true? What about other aspects?

Comment: I think any of the verbs you mentioned can be used with *away* in the sense you are talking about, at least in informal context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the stacked prepositions "away at" mean in this sentence?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10675/what-do-the-stacked-prepositions-away-at-mean-in-this-sentence) In all such cases, the "away" element implies one or more of *continuously, repetitively, gradually*.

Comment: I beg to disagree. I think I'm asking it from a different perspective. Plz note that I have quoted the definition in the first place. @FumbleFingers

Comment: I'm not sure how useful it is for learners to study lexical aspects. (It might be, though I think it's unnecessary.) This question probably fits our Linguistics stack better. (To elaborate a bit, asking whether a verb in a specific sentence is telic or atelic could fit ELL, but asking if all atelic verbs (along with other aspects) always work with a specific meaning of *away* is probably better on our Linguistics stack.) Also, I think you probably are mixing up lexical aspects (dynamic with atelic), and grammatical aspects (e.g. progressive, which can be thought of as an imperfective aspect).

Comment: It takes a pretty contrived context with some verbs *(We couldn't survive without the ozone layer shielding us from hard radiation. Unrecognised until recently, it's been **protecting away** since humans first evolved)*. And some of OP's offerings *(explain away, warn away)* have well-established usages *not* involving this "continuous" sense, which can make it even harder to contrive a valid context for the usage under consideration. It takes some doing to get your head around *It wasn't working [going?] at all yesterday, but it's been **going away** for hours today*.

Comment: "His father kept warning away furiously, but he wouldn't listen. His teacher had been explaining away relentlessly, but he just couldn't understand it." Does it sound natural? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Kinzle B: I specifically pointed out that *explain away* is a well-established usage not involving the "continuous" sense, which therefore makes your example come across as a bit "weird". It occurs to me that a possible "rule of thumb" is *VERBing **away*** mostly only works where *VERBing* could reasonably be used adjectivally *(Molly is a working stiff; Chattering children annoy me)*. So your ***warning*** version also sounds "quirky", as would *He ignored his warning father*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is great; just one more Q: by the same token, would *hit away* & *jump away*  sound odd as well?

Comment: In the whole of Google Books I can only find [this single instance](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IFVOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA347&dq=%22was+jumping+away%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22was%20jumping%20away%22&f=false) of *[was] **jumping away*** reflecting the usage we're talking about. Arguably it's "less-than-ideal" because ***jump*** is so often used with ***away*** in the standard prepositional sense of *away **from** [something]* - and it's not really an "atelic" verb either. But *in some contexts*, you can certainly get away with ***jumping*** or ***hitting away*** in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

> He laughed for an hour.   He was laughing away for an hour.

Ok, that's atelic, and this sense of "away" works with the continuous aspect.

> "I'm sorry.   I'm trying not to laugh." 
>   "It's ok.   I won't be offended.   ✓Laugh away.   ✓Laugh for an hour, if you must."

It even seems to work in the imperative mode, no continuous aspect needed.

I certainly can't test every verb with these models, but it looks like the relationship between "away" and "for an hour" should be consistent.   I suspect that atelic constructions without objects will work.

What if the atelic construction includes an object?

> ✓He was pushing my buttons for an hour.   ✗He was pushing my buttons away for an hour.   ✗He was pushing away my buttons for an hour.   ✓He was pushing away for an hour.

It looks like this sense of "away" isn't available when the construction includes a direct object.

What about telic constructions?

> ✓It grew in an hour.   ✗It was growing in an hour.   ✗It grew away in an hour.

I can't seem to find a telic construction in the continuous aspect.   I can't seem to find a telic construction that uses this sense of "away".   That could be evidence that such constructions don't exist, or it could merely be evidence that I personally don't have the skill to find them.   Either way, I can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

To *go away* means to remove oneself from somewhere.  To *make go away* means to cause to be gone.  These are common verb phrases in English.

Logically connected, when you say "X away", one of the meanings can be

- there's an amount of something
- X makes this amount of something go away or become less
- this is, was, or will be occurring over time.

> whittle away
>
> fade away
>
> ponder away

The thing you are "Xing away" can be anything as long as it makes sense with this meaning and verb.you're doing that over time.

> I whittled away at the wall with my crowbar, and eventually tore down the wall.
>
> Slowly the pain faded away.
>
> I pondered away at the possibilities, but could not think of a reason why he would do that.

Of course, *away* can just mean "in a direction opposite," sometimes with "from here" implied.

> take away
>
> get away
>
> jump away
>
> kicked away
>
> flew away

It can also mean "as much as you want" - informal, typically used imperatively in conversation:

> A: I would like to help him.  (B doesn't like the "him" and would be too glad to let A handle him)
>
> B: Be my guest! Help away!